# "How to edit" side gadget fell down below

Tags: bug, edits, design

Here's a screenshot of the editing page as can be seen from far away:

> [image]

As you can barely see, the side gadget called "How to edit" with formatting tips and such is below the "Save edits" button. This just happened to me right after I posted a question and without refreshing the page pressed "edit".

([Link to reproduce](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/233836/edit))

Comment: I refreshed this page, pressed "edit" and it also happens to it.

Comment: Also, there is a suspiciously large amount of empty space between the bottom of the gadget and the top of the blue footer. I wonder what that accommodates for.

Comment: Typical CSS bug - some width value is incorrect.

Comment: Closing as dupe of newer report as it got official response.

Answer (score -3):

OK, spoke too soon! This is definitely not a Zoom issue. I had missed the link to reproduce.

---

---

From experience, I would put it at your browsers Zoom!

Try one of the following methods to reset it:

- pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>
- pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+/-</kbd> until it resets
- using the browsers view menu to reset the zoom to 100% ([Steps for common browsers](http://help.smartsheet.com/customer/portal/articles/506736-browser-zoom))

On the other hand, if this does get fixed via the zoom reset, the onus will be on the devs then to fix the CSS Zoom issue!

Comment: Nope: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JaQHN.gif